# R convert string to variable

Tags: r, quantmod

I'm using the [quantmod](http://www.quantmod.com/) package in `R` to pull historical data from yahoo finance.

To use the package I create a list of tickers like so:

```
symbols <- c("MSFT", "ORCL", "AAPL", "FB")
```

To get the historical data I call the quantlib method getSymbols:

```
try(getSymbols(sym, src="yahoo"))
```

This creates variables in my environment called `MSFT`, `ORCL`, `APPL` and `FB`.

To calculate a correlation between MSFT and ORCL with closing prices I can use

```
cor(Cl(MSFT), Cl(ORCL))
```

To get:

```
           ORCL.Close
MSFT.Close  0.6597159
```

How can I make this generic so that i can pull say 20 symbols and run the correlation between them?

I don't know how to refer to a variable given a string. ie I have the string "MFST", how do I refer to the variable `MSFT` ?

I've got the string "MFST" and "ORCL" how can I use that to write `cor(Cl(MSFT), Cl(ORCL))`

Comment: `get("MSFT")` will give you the variable `MSFT`. That said, you may be better off putting each of these in a list, which would let you do nice `apply` things to all of them.

Comment: @Gregor, wow, you are right.  So simple, but I have no idea how to search for that.  Could you please put that in an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way is to store the data in an environment, and then loop over all the objects in the environment with `eapply`:

```
library(quantmod)
dataEnv <- new.env()
getSymbols("MSFT;ORCL;AAPL;FB", env=dataEnv)
# Extract the close column from all objects,
# then merge all close columns into one object
cl <- do.call(merge, eapply(dataEnv, Cl))
# note the warning in the Details section of ?cor
# regarding the use of "pairwise.complete.obs"
cor(cl, use="pairwise.complete.obs")
#            AAPL.Close ORCL.Close MSFT.Close   FB.Close
# AAPL.Close  1.0000000  0.6467283  0.2528689 -0.5997337
# ORCL.Close  0.6467283  1.0000000  0.6597159  0.8211939
# MSFT.Close  0.2528689  0.6597159  1.0000000  0.8979836
# FB.Close   -0.5997337  0.8211939  0.8979836  1.0000000
```

Comment: great answer, thank you! I really like the idea of providing my own environment

Answer (score 2):

The `get()` function does what you're looking for, e.g. `get("MSFT")`.

Generally, you might do better to store everything in a list rather than in the global environment. If you want to do something to all of them having them in a list makes it a bit easier. I talk a little more about that in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/903061), though I'm sure there are better discussions out there.

**Edit:** In this case, rather than a `list`, putting things in their own environment as in @Josh Ulrich's answer is probably best.